# Doctrine - select last 4 rows from table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm using Symfony/Doctrine. 
I'm trying to select last 4 rows from table, but im getting error.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT c FROM DprocMainBundle:Courses c ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4'
);

$course = $query->getResult();
```

This is my query but it shows error.

> Expected end of string, got 'LIMIT'

How should i use limit, and get the LAST 4 rows?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setMaxResults()` to limit the number of results.

```
$course = $query->setMaxResults(4)->getResult();
```

If you want to use this for pagination you can add a `setFirstResult()` call.

```
 $course = $query->setMaxResults(4)->setFirstResult(10)->getResult();
```

Comment: But does it display the last 4 rows or just 4 rows?

Comment: it will return the first results of the set - you can change first / last by changing the result order ... i added a hint to how to set the offset to my answer, too :)