# Doctrine 2.1 performance issue

Tags: php, mysql, performance, symfony, doctrine

Recently I faced with doctrine 2.1 performance issue. In my request I have a lot of "**LEFT JOINS**", "**WHERE**" and "**WHERE IN**" clauses, and I need total count + specific set of records based on limit and offset.
First of all doctrine 2.1 doesn't support MySQL option **Limit**. I tried to attach Limit to the query, but every time I got "***error expected end of string got 'limit'***".
I tried to use

```
$queryBuilder
    ->setMaxResults(25)
    ->setFirstResult(10);
```

as it was suggested in many articles, but as it said in the documentation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

> If your query contains a fetch-joined collection specifying the result
>   limit methods are not working as you would expect.

Which mean that if you expect 25 rows per page, you can get for example 18.
Doctine 2.1 doesn't have paginator by default as doctrine 2.2, so everyone suggest to use doctrine extention https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Paginate/Paginate.php, but it's also lame and decrease the performance. As I understood, it sends 2 requests: 1 request gets all the date without a limit and offset to count total count and the second request is a "WHERE IN" request with ids of the specific entities. It's too slow to me.
So you probably want to know what is my solution:

```
$data = $oQuery->getArrayResult();
return array(
'data' => array_slice($data, $iStart, $iLimit),
'count' => count($data)
);
```

If you have better and faster solution, please share it with me.

Comment: Maybe you should stop using Doctrine 2.1?

Comment: I wish I could:)

Answer (score 0):

While your query is absent from the question, you have only two options: either use raw SQL with all necessary `LIMIT`s or upgrade Doctrine version.

Comment: I also thought about using raw query, but this is not an option. There are 2 ways to do that: build SQL and give it to doctrine, but you'll get the same error, that I mentioned above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607277/doctrine-select-last-4-rows-from-table
2-d way - run SQL query without doctrine using PHP functions, but this is also not an option. I hope it's obvious why.

Comment: Update the doctrine is very risky it might harm the entire project. I don't want to be responsible for that.

Comment: @Hevyweb I don't get what is the problem that prevents you from using Doctrine DBAL(`$entityManager->getConnection()`) to execute raw sql.

Comment: @Hevyweb "very risky" - if your project is covered with tests, this is not risky at all. If not - it's time to create those tests. They will save you tons of time when you find that you absolutely need to use never version of some software, or even change virtually anything in your own code.